# ELSE was unexpected at this time

Tags: if-statement, cmd, conemu

I frequently work on the Windows command line within [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/) and occasionally, after working in a given window for some time, get the following unexpected error:

```
ELSE was unexpected at this time.
```

Currently, it occurred after pasting about 150 lines of `rm` commands (may be unrelated).

Once I get that error, I cannot use the `ELSE` statement in that window; I must start a new shell process, at which point my scripts work as expected.  For example, once that error occurs in a window, I observe the following:

```
C:\> IF DEFINED AN_ENV_VAR (ECHO YES) ELSE ECHO NO
ELSE was unexpected at this time.
C:\> IF NOT DEFINED AN_ENV_VAR (ECHO YES) ELSE ECHO NO
ELSE was unexpected at this time.
C:\> IF DEFINED AN_ENV_VAR (ECHO YES)
C:\> IF NOT DEFINED AN_ENV_VAR (ECHO YES)
YES
```

A new shell gives expected results:

```
C:\> IF DEFINED AN_ENV_VAR (ECHO YES) ELSE ECHO NO
NO
C:\> IF NOT DEFINED AN_ENV_VAR (ECHO YES) ELSE ECHO NO
YES
C:\> IF DEFINED AN_ENV_VAR (ECHO YES)
C:\> IF NOT DEFINED AN_ENV_VAR (ECHO YES)
YES
```

Is there any way to fix the current shell?

Comment: The only way `ELSE` can be `unexpected` is if `ELSE` is provided prior to the message being output. We'd need to see your code, or supposed  '150 lines of `rm` commands', to help you debug it!

Comment: Cmd has some options which may be changed during run. Try to read `cmd /?`.

Comment: @Compo the `rm` commands were simply `rm` then filename, although the first one was `rm` then 150 long filenames...maybe overrunning command line buffer...then I did run some company batch scripts (which usually work OK)...I'll provide more info when I can reproduce

Comment: Well the `ELSE` error is obviously coming from a company run batch script, then. All we need is every line of your batch files which contain the string `ELSE`. You can output those easily using `FindStr`, e.g. `FindStr /SIC:"ELSE" *.bat` or `FindStr /SIC:"ELSE" *.cmd`

Comment: @Compo but why would the error seem to stay around?  Wouldn't that script just throw an error?  Why can I never use `ELSE` again?

Comment: We need information, I hope you're not expecting us to guess the entire contents of all of  your company batch scripts. Your question is too broad at this time, and should be closed as such unless you rectify matters!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the environment variables should contain a miss adding else statement.

Please check the expanded values of the DEFINED AN_ENV_VAR.

One way to reproduce the error is

```
set var=123 else echo abc
if %var%==123 echo ok
```

When the var expanded. There will be a additional else statement. Then the error is raised.

```
ELSE was unexpected at this time.
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your path doesn't have space in any folder other wise it will through error "ELSE was unexpected at this time." for batch file running same we faced while one of our project